# How to use ComboBox SelectedItem inside of ItemsControl DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am working on a form to add items to an order. What I have for the items area XAML is this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ServiceItems" ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceOrderItems}" Width="737" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="193" Visibility="{Binding ShowServiceItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="320*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="54*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="47*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems, Path=DataContext.ItemsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems, Path=DataContext.CommandAddServiceItem}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Available, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="2" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="3" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Rate, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="4" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="5" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Taxable, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="6" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Closed, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="7" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is my MVVM class:

```
namespace ServiceOrders
{
    public class SalesOrderItem
    {
        public Int64 ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Available { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public bool Taxable { get; set; }
        public bool Closed { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Item;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceOrders.SalesOrderItem> ItemsList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceOrders.SalesOrderItem> ServiceOrderItems { get; set; }

    public SalesOrderControlViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<ServiceOrders.SalesOrderItem>();
        ServiceOrderItems = new ObservableCollection<ServiceOrders.SalesOrderItem>();
    }
}
```

All of my bindings seem to work except on the ComboBox. I want to pull from a list of items (`ItemsList`) but then I want to add the SelectedItem to the `ServiceOrderItems`. When I selected the item it does add it but only adds the `SalesOrderItem.Item` and won't add the Description, Quantity, etc.

How do I achieve what I am wanting to do? I've tried the following:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems, Path=DataContext.ItemsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems, Path=DataContext.SelectedServiceItem, Mode=TwoWay}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" DisplayMemberPath="Item">
```

But this just sets all of the item lines ComboBoxes to the same thing. I have also tried doing it by the `SelectionChanged` event and then trying to get the SelectedItem and adding it to the `ServiceOrderItems`.

I've looked all over and can't find anything that meets what exactly I am wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

String is added because you have bind **`SelectedItem`** with string value and I suspect in your command you add the selected item in command.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems,
                                Path=DataContext.ItemsList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Item, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

***Bind SelectedItem to object of type SalesOrderItem say SelectedSalesOrderItem*** so that you get access to complete object.

And you don't need to override ToString() if it's just to show Item in comboBox. You can use **`DisplayMemberPath`** property to show particular property on UI from object.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ServiceItems,
                                Path=DataContext.ItemsList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSalesOrderItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Item">
```

Comment: Would I need a property for my SalesOrderItem class for SelectedSalesOrderItem?

Comment: Yeah you need to have the property in class `SalesOrderControlViewModel` for this.